# Xcode 6 Toolchain Build Error

Tags: ios, xcode, widget, swift, toolchain

I'm trying to make a Today Extension, so I opened up a new Xcode 6 project, and created a Today Extension. I then Built and Ran the project but it failed with this error:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-stdlib-tool failed with exit code 1
```

I literally didn't change anything, and I've only use Xcode for playground before now. How do I fix this??

Comment: I started a new project, revoked my certificate and created a new one, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This error message is very misleading. It happened to me when I am trying to run without proper certificate on a physical device. First check if you are getting the same error when trying to run on a simulator, if yes you need to dig deep, if not check your certificates.